# Why is this root certificate hard to find?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm chasing a root certificate from verisign.

> Issuer: C=US, O=VeriSign, Inc., OU=Class 3 Public Primary
>   Certification Authority
>
> The serial# is: 70:ba:e4:1d:10:d9:29:34:b6:38:ca:7b:03:cc:ba:bf
>
> The dates are: Jan 29 00:00:00 1996 GMT -> Aug  1 23:59:59 2028 GMT

I'm not have any success in locating this.  Many VeriSign roots are listed [here](https://www.symantec.com/theme/roots).

Maybe I'm missing something in my cert understanding.  Shouldn't CA's be publishing their root CA's?  i.e. Shouldn't they be shouting "Here are my roots.  Come get em."  Why am I having such a hard time finding this root cert?

Comment: So what do you want to know? Are you asking for the certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the serial number the certificate, or thumbprint, or SPKI, you can easily find root and intermediate certificates on [crt.sh](https://crt.sh).

https://crt.sh/?id=162

This certificate is very old and is not trusted by all certificate stores these days (NSS for example). It's 1024-bit RSA with an MD2 digest. I wouldn't be surprised if Symantec / DigiCert considered this root deprecated.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of crt.sh.  I'm lost on the concept of a "deprecated" certificate.  It seems, either the cert is real/valid or on the CRL.  If valid, why doesn't the issuer publish it?  If not, why doesn't the issuer revoke it?  I have not seen any "list of deprecated certificates" in my search.

Comment: @Doug the authority can just decide to stop providing certificates signed by this specific certficate. Since certificates are typically provided for 1 year, after waiting some time and stopping to renew old certificate you can have a root certificate not used anymore by any certificate in the wild, hence being deprecated.